# my nodemanager stops after starting

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, shutdown, connection-refused

NodeManager in my slave node stops after starting. I have 3 node 1 master and 2 slaves when I use command `start-yarn.sh` my resourcemanager and nodemanagers start correctly but when I query in hive my mapreduce dont start running and stops at kill command when I check my nodemanager logs in both slaves I just saw that my nodemanagers are shutdown and this is my error:

```
FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager 
      org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: 
      Call From  to 0.0.0.0:8031 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: 
      Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

I have searched for this problem and I did not find any clue. How to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this property in `yarn-site.xml` file for all nodes,

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>ip_or_fqdn_or_hostname_of_resourcemanager_host</value>
</property>
```

Comment: thank you so much this solution solve my problem really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Please add these properties in these files  :-

> **mapred-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

> **yarn-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>ip_of_resource_manager</value>
</property>
```

Comment: thank you so much this solution solve my problem really appreciate that

Comment: @franklinsijo no sir u misunderstood me i have faced this issue in cluster setup so i have given the answer. don't think like that i have copied your answer

Comment: Well the similar answer was already given, if you feel the already provided answer is correct you can upvote/comment to support it. StackOverflow does not encourage duplicate answers and they can get flagged for deletion.

Comment: i am new to this community , so don't have idea too much , from now onward i will take care of this ,please don't think in wrong manner

Comment: @Hari Cool... Nothing in wrong intent, good you understood how SO works. I will take down my comment :)